# django-nose - Exclude directory in coverage

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-nose

I'm using `django-nose` in order to measuring coverage of my test suite. 
I followed this [doc](http://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/coverage.html) to do this.

With the standard configuration works well, and i succeed in cover all my application.

I would exclude `views` directory from the coverage without install new packages, so I tried to use `--ignore-files` parameter in this way:

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=apps.my_app',
    '--ignore-files=^views\\.'
]
```

My project structure is

```
+- root
|-- src
|--- main
|---- apps
|----- my_app
|------ views
|--- test
|---- main
|----- apps
|------ my_app
|------- views
```

And I run the test suite from project root with the following command:

```
python src\main\manage.py test --noinput main
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly, I mean that django-nose seems ignore this option and views directory is included in the coverage.

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure coverage.py to exclude files from analysis, and to exclude files from coverage's report. I've done this successfully using django-nose.

Add a [.coveragerc](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.2/config.html#config) file, in the same directory coverage.py is being run (where you run your tests from), with something like the following ->

```
[run]
omit = 
    my/folder/*


[report]
omit = 
    my/folder/*
```

Comment: +1 This was very useful – I had [run] set up correctly, but not [report], so was still getting a load of noise in my output!

Comment: This worked, however, I had to call the config file `.coveragerc`

Comment: Thanks, I think the original text had a typo, fixing per your comment.